# Why does Ajax not reach the server?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a simple ajax form where I need to send a response to my server. But whenever I submit I get this error :

```
Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /designer/addOne/
[31/Jul/2017 12:49:12] "POST /designer/addOne/ HTTP/1.1" 403 2502
```

I am pretty sure everything is well configured and that there's no error with the `csrf_token`.

**HTML**

```
<form id="addOneForm">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input id="addOne" type="button" value="Next">
</form>
```

**Ajax (JS)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '#addOne', function(e){
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'/designer/addOne/',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        data:{
            csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('#addOneForm input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
        },
        success: function(response) {
        }
    });
  });
});
```

What am I doing wrong ? (For the server I'm using Django)

Comment: use jquery ajax's error function to get the error accurately ...   `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, ex) {
    console.log(textStatus + "," + ex + "," + jqXHR.responseText);
   }`

Comment: @Jana To resume, it is just saying that the csrf_token is either incorrect or missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I still don't know from what the error was caused I just changed the ajax to :

```
var form_data = new FormData($('#addOneForm')[0]);
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'/designer/addOne/',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    data : form_data,
    success: function(response) {
    }
});
```

Which made it work.